# What is this training device used by Vasyl Lomachenko called?

Tags: equipment, training, boxing

[Video](https://twitter.com/VasylLomachenko/status/838193852427051008) from a [Vasyl Lomachenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasyl_Lomachenko) twitter account.

[image: Training device]

What is the name of this device or similar type of device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Sports Vision Trainer ([SVT](http://www.sportsvision.com.au/svt/)):

[image: SVT]

The SVTs come in different sizes and Lomachenko uses the smaller one with 32 lights.
They also have the picture of him using it on their [website](http://www.sportsvision.com.au/information/svt-produces-world-champions/).

Answer (score 4):

While I can’t provide the specific name to the device you show, I can tell you that it has many uses, one of which is improving hand to eye coordination.  A company called [Dynavision](https://www.dynavisioninternational.com/) makes a very similar product called [D2(Dynavsion Dynamic Motor)](https://products.dynavisioninternational.com/products/d2) that is used in sports training and rehabilitation.

Listed benefits of it are:

- Incorporates gross motor skills
- Progresses neuro-cognitive abilities
- Expands peripheral awareness
- Trains reaction time
- Improves functional mobility
- Develops enhanced balance

It’s easy to see why a boxer would seek out this type of training device, as it can be used to improve his boxing abilities.